# How to get the record from table as hourly basis in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called DailySales(ID int,Date date,Time Time,CashSale Money,CardSale money,TotalSale money).Now I want to below result...

```
                  Date : 04-06-2015

                  Time : 09:01 - 10:00
CashSale           CardSale                   TotalSale
10000.00           15000.00                   25000.00

                 Time : 10:01 - 11:00
CashSale           CardSale                   TotalSale
20000.00           15000.00                   35000.00
.
.
.
```

Please help me,
thanks..

Comment: If you posted a query, it is not visible.

Comment: Take a look to these guidelines: [ask] and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you're wanting to store both a date and a time, it's usually better to store them in a single column of type `datetime2` (or `datetime` on older versions).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a tip how this can be achieved. This is just a maximum of what sql can do for you. The rest should be done in report:

Preparing the data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      Date DATE ,
      Time TIME ,
      CashSale MONEY ,
      CardSale MONEY ,
      TotalSale MONEY
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '20150603', '09:30', 10, 5, 15 ),
        ( '20150604', '09:02', 10, 5, 15 ),
        ( '20150604', '09:30', 10, 5, 15 ),
        ( '20150604', '10:00', 10, 5, 15 ),
        ( '20150604', '11:01', 10, 5, 15 ),
        ( '20150604', '11:30', 10, 5, 15 ),
        ( '20150604', '12:30', 10, 5, 15 );
```

Query:

```
WITH times
AS ( SELECT   *
     FROM ( VALUES
          ( CAST('09:01' AS TIME), CAST('10:00' AS TIME)),
          ( CAST('10:01' AS TIME), CAST('11:00' AS TIME)),
          ( CAST('11:01' AS TIME), CAST('12:00' AS TIME)) ) times ( StartTime, EndTime )
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    ( SELECT    t.Date ,
                        ti.StartTime ,
                        ti.EndTime ,
                        SUM(CashSale) CashSale ,
                        SUM(CardSale) CardSale ,
                        SUM(TotalSale) TotalSale
              FROM      @t t
                        JOIN times ti ON t.Time BETWEEN ti.StartTime AND ti.EndTime
              WHERE     Date = '20150604'
              GROUP BY  t.Date ,
                        ti.StartTime ,
                        ti.EndTime
            ) t UNPIVOT( Amount FOR SaleType IN ( [CashSale], [CardSale], [TotalSale] ) ) u
    ORDER BY Date ,
            StartTime ,
            EndTime ,
            CASE SaleType
              WHEN 'TotalSale' THEN 1
              WHEN 'CashSale' THEN 2
              WHEN 'CardSale' THEN 3
            END
```

Output:

```
Date        StartTime           EndTime             Amount  SaleType
2015-06-04  09:01:00.0000000    10:00:00.0000000    45.00   TotalSale
2015-06-04  09:01:00.0000000    10:00:00.0000000    30.00   CashSale
2015-06-04  09:01:00.0000000    10:00:00.0000000    15.00   CardSale
2015-06-04  11:01:00.0000000    12:00:00.0000000    30.00   TotalSale
2015-06-04  11:01:00.0000000    12:00:00.0000000    20.00   CashSale
2015-06-04  11:01:00.0000000    12:00:00.0000000    10.00   CardSale
```

**EDIT:**

You can create a table:

```
Times(StartTime TIME, EndTime TIME)
```

Insert all 24 rows in it:

```
INSERT INTO Times VALUES
( CAST('09:01' AS TIME), CAST('10:00' AS TIME)),
( CAST('10:01' AS TIME), CAST('11:00' AS TIME)),
( CAST('11:01' AS TIME), CAST('12:00' AS TIME)),
....
( CAST('23:01' AS TIME), CAST('00:00' AS TIME))
```

The you can use it:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    t.Date ,
                    ti.StartTime ,
                    ti.EndTime ,
                    SUM(CashSale) CashSale ,
                    SUM(CardSale) CardSale ,
                    SUM(TotalSale) TotalSale
          FROM      @t t
                    JOIN Times ti ON t.Time BETWEEN ti.StartTime AND ti.EndTime
          WHERE     Date = '20150604'
          GROUP BY  t.Date ,
                    ti.StartTime ,
                    ti.EndTime
        ) t UNPIVOT( Amount FOR SaleType IN ( [CashSale], [CardSale], [TotalSale] ) ) u
ORDER BY Date ,
        StartTime ,
        EndTime ,
        CASE SaleType
          WHEN 'TotalSale' THEN 1
          WHEN 'CashSale' THEN 2
          WHEN 'CardSale' THEN 3
        END
```

Comment: thanks,But I need the dynamic time, that means It will show whole day hourly basis record of any particular date.

Comment: Create table times ( StartTime, EndTime ) and insert 24 rows in it. Then instead of times cte use that table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that your best bet is to store the date/time together in a `datetime` or `datetime2` column rather than just storing the time, then use can use the `datepart` function to get the hour.

Assuming The `Time` column is actually a `DateTime`, you could do something like:

```
SELECT Date, 
       datepart(Hour, Time) AS Hour, 
       sum(CashSale) AS ByCash, 
       sum(CardSale) AS ByCard, 
       sum(TotalSale) AS NetSale
FROM   DailySales
GROUP BY Date, datepart(Hour, Time)
```

This would split it up hour by hour, on the hour (e.g 09:00:00 to 09:59:59, 10:00:00 to 10:59:59, etc.). If you wanted to offset where the split takes place, for example at 1 minute past the hour, then you can use the `dateadd` function, for example `dateadd(minute, -1, Time)`, in place of `Time`.

If you're storing the string in some other way, for example as a string, then you'd want to group by some string expression based on that, e.g. `left(Time, 2)`

Comment: Also, more recent versions of SQL Server have a native `Time` type - assuming this is the type of your time, `datepart()` works on this too.